# How to relate records to a system user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an association between reports and users. I'm now writing a cronjob that needs to add reports automatically in case of inactivity. Problem is that the user/user_id on the report record is mandatory. What's the best approach to add this "system user", could it be done without creating a record in the database? The user class is also used by Devise to authenticate, so I'd rather not put extra records. Thanks for your point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Add the system user to the DB, prevent it from logging in. Associate it with everything created through cron jobs.

Comment: And how would I refer to that specific user? Since this is a migration that will be executed on multiple environments with varying amounts of users, I cannot rely on the ID.

Comment: You could give it a special username and then look it up by name?

Answer (score 0):

The best option for me would be to modify the report model to make `user` optional using `optional: true`, which you cannot do apparently.

My next approach would be creating a new user `logger` (or something similar) that will be used as a filler for inactivity logs. Then change the signing in procedure to only accept `active` users, which apparently you cannot do.

My last resort would be to use the `admin` user and add the log in their name.

Comment: I was reading about Null Object, but couldn't really figure out how I could leverage that for this use-case. Any experience with that maybe?

Comment: You cannot save a Null Object, you either have to change/extend your user model or your log model. OR use a placeholder for user in your logs.

Comment: @RezaKazemirad
Making the user optional seems like a bad idea and will cause a lot of nil checks in the rest of the code.

Comment: @pascalbetz it depends on the rest of the code. Only logger model is effected and it shouldn't be hard to customize it just for that model.